# increment a column in SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my View

```
Create View [MyView] as

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY col1 ) AS id, col1, col2, col3
FROM(
    Select col1, col2, col3 From Table1
    Union All
    Select col1, col2, col3 From Table2 ) AS MyResults
GO
```

when I run the view the row number is not matching with the row number when I use a where condition. For example `select * from myview` I get 20 records with Mark in col1 getting row number as 15. But when I use a filter `select * from myview where col1 = 'Mark'` and getting row now as 14. Kindly let me know how to make this stable

Comment: you mean the rownumber's changing? well, that stands to reason. `where` will prevent rows from even appearing the result set, preventing the row_number() from applying to them. If you want the same row_number() no matter what you have in `where`, then use a `having` clause instead, which would apply AFTER row_number is applied.

Comment: You're not using a dynamically-generated-every-time row number to *identify* records in the data, are you?  Records really should have their own identifiers in the data at rest, not dynamically assigned to them when querying the data.

Comment: I agree I also want the record no to be stable. but when I run for many records it is not stable and giving some no which is not the actual

Comment: `row_number()` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. This is the way it works.

Comment: @marc even that won't work if the dat changes over time. You need to explain what you need the number to be unchanging for to help us point you to teh correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the confusion: you are expecting the view to create a result set; but as you've discovered, views don't work that way. What you're doing is equivalent to:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY col1 ) AS id, col1, col2, col3
FROM
(
    Select col1, col2, col3 From Table1 where col1 = 'Mark'
    Union All
    Select col1, col2, col3 From Table2 where col1 = 'Mark'
) AS MyResults
```

What you want is to create a result set that will defines your ranking. One way to do this is with a common table expression:

```
WITH MyResults(RowNumber, id, col1, col2, col3)
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY col1 ) AS id, col1, col2, col3
    FROM(
        Select col1, col2, col3 From Table1
        Union All
        Select col1, col2, col3 From Table2 ) AS InnerResults
)
SELECT * FROM MyResults WHERE col1 = 'Mark'
```

Comment: Even this is going to change over time if the values in col1 are differnt.  Suppose it had A, J and M as values and someone adds a record with a value of B, then J will have an id of 3 insted of the 2 it previously had.

Comment: I'm not sure we're in agreement about what @vijay-kumar meant by "stable". If you want an immutable ranking, then of course you would select this into a table, and don't touch the table after that. I assumed that by "stable", he meant that the ranking would be the same regardless of the condition that was used to select records.